# Help with interactive macbook cover image design

Tags: css, html

I'm very new to web design and for one of my assignments i have to recreate the apple web page.

The issue is that I need the images on this list to be above the word, not next to it

http://codepen.io/kenthompson/pen/EaVWdW

so as you can see, i need the image of the macbook pro to be above the text, not next to it as it is. How can i get the image above the text?

Comment: Hi Ken, please ask one question at a time. YOu might also want to clarify using screenshots... for example, I don't see a "Magic Mouse image" so have no idea what you're referring to. But again, edit the question to ask one thing first. You're more likely to get help that way. You might also want to include some of the relevant code dealing with the question directly on here so people don't have look your entire code. As it stands I'll be voting to close, but will retract my vote if its edited.

Comment: Sorry, first time using this site.  I've condensed my issue in to one code pen. http://codepen.io/kenthompson/pen/EaVWdW

if you click on "mac" "apps" "pro apps" "servers" or "accessories" it changes the items on the list above it.  I need those images to be above the text, and not next to them

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about coding a web site much more than the actual design of a web site (since Apple design is simply being replicated) and this question is a better fit for StackOverflow.com where users are more adept at addressing "how do I code this" questions.

Comment: @Scott then why you not vote for close ? when you have enough reputation ..?

Comment: @AnantDabhi note the "migrated" message. My comment was posted on GraphicDesign.StackExchange.com